# How to execute code after Angular Material animations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, frontend, angular-material

I'm using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/) on a website. Being a responsive-framework, it handles rendering at different window-sizes. When changing the window size, it adds some animations of the layout changing and controls moving around

Example: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList (open the link and resize the window)

[image]

I have some WebGL canvas on the tiles shown on the example that need to be redrawn after the animation completes (and the container has it's final dimensions).

How can I get some `callback` or `promise` for the UI animations to be complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for this problem, is to add the attribute `md-on-layout` to `md-grid-list` ([docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdGridList)).

Example:

**HTML**:

```
<md-grid-list md-on-layout="update($event)" ...>
  <md-grid-tile>...</md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

**Controller**:

```
$scope.update = function($event){
    console.log("Updating layout."); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute `md-on-layout` specified as part of `md-grid-list` directive to pass an *expression* or a *function* to it. This gets executed once your layout changes.

**Directive use**

```
<md-grid-list md-cols-xs="1" 
  md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-md="4" md-cols-gt-md="6" 
  md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="2:2" 
  md-gutter="12px" md-gutter-gt-sm="8px" 
  md-on-layout="afterLayout()">
    <md-grid-tile class="gray" md-rowspan="3" md-colspan="2" md-colspan-sm="1" md-colspan-xs="1">
    <md-grid-tile-footer>
      <h3>#1: (3r x 2c)</h3>
    </md-grid-tile-footer>
  </md-grid-tile>

</md-grid-list>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.afterLayout = function () {
  console.log("Layout complete");
}
```

I have created a codepen with the implementation which does a `console.log` on layout change: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWwmNw